# Continuously send data with open connection using Websocket in Python

Tags: python, websocket, centos

This is my first time programming in Python and needs help with using websocket. I'm using the example from [here](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) as the example. The project I'm working requires that I send update to the server constantly with the connection open. I'd used the extension for firefox to connect to the websocket and knows that it works and I can send data to it. However, I'm using having problem with modifying the code in main to keep the connection open so that I can keep sending data. The on_open runs only once at connection open

```
    import websocket
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_open = on_open,
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)

    ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: You're closing the web socket as soon as you write 3 items.

Comment: This is from the  sample code from the websocket-client example. I'm looking to modify this sample so that I can keep the connection open until I'm done with sending data which could be 10 send to 10000. I can use the on_open to send the initial config and then return to the main to continue sending my data.

Comment: I'm able to make it work. I used the create_connection instead and just have it loop after the connection to send data.

Answer (score 2):

```
ws= websocket.create_connection(ws_url)

ws.send(init_data) # send the initial data
while True:
   # get the data to send
   data = process_data(get_data())
   if not data:
      break
   
   try:
      ws.send(json.dumps(data))
   except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      break
   finally:
      ws.close()
```

Comment: How'd you get the `process_data` function?